# How to make sure rectangles that are drawn on an image are in the correct relative position in HTML code?

Tags: html, css, image, scale

I have a set of images hosted on an external webserver. The resolution of the images is not the same. Associated with each image are many co-ordinates one example would be:

`{"top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;}`

Each set of co-ordinates defines a rectangle on the image.

The task is to draw each of the rectangles on the image with a red border and red transparent interior...

I managed to come up with the following code that does appear to work by adapting similar examples on the web and also utilising tools to write code that will assist in this task:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    /* Set the image as the background */
    .image-container {
      background-image: url("my-img-1.jpg");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 75%; /* Adjust this value to maintain the aspect ratio of the image */
    }
    
    /* Define the rectangles using absolute positioning */
    .rectangle {
      position: absolute;
      border: 2px solid red;
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2); /* Light shade of transparent red */
      z-index: 1; /* Ensure the rectangles appear above the image */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image-container">
    <!-- Define the rectangles using the provided coordinates -->
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;"></div>
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 50%; left: 60%; width: 20%; height: 30%;"></div>
    <!-- Add more rectangles as needed -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I can generate this code for each of my images and add as many rectangles as required.

The problem I have is that I want to ensure that regardless of the size of the original image, and regardless of the display screen size or browser window size or any other variable, the rectangles will appear in the correct position relative to the background image.

I am unsure if my code currently achieves this.

Specifically this part and the `width, height, padding-bottom` attribute. I don't see why we have the `75%` isn't that going to mean the image is pushed in horizontally and so the rectangles will be in the wrong place? Even though they actually look fine!

```
  .image-container {
      background-image: url("my-img-1.jpg");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 75%; /* Adjust this value to maintain the aspect ratio of the image */
    }
```

Can anyone with more experience tell me if I need to adapt my code at all to make sure the rectangles can never be placed incorrectly and giving a misleading image regardless of any external factors.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine except you must alter that % padding depending on the aspect-ratio of the image.

What is happening is that an element is being created that has the same aspect ratio as the image. This is done by making the element have a height of 0 but adding padding at the bottom. In the case  you show the padding is three quarters of the WIDTH of the element (padding is calculated relative to the width of the element, not its height).

So you have an element created with aspect ratio 4 / 3.

The image is then drawn as a background and if the aspect ratio is the same the contain will ensure it exactly fills the element.

Your %s which place the red rectangles then work fine as they are placed relatively using % offsets within the image.

So, for each image you must also use the correct padding.

You could do this at runtime using JavaScript but you have not tagged JS, and given you are anyway having to build in some parameters already you could put the % padding into the style of each image.

Here's an example for a square image and for an image with aspect-ratio 2 / 3.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /* Set the image as the background */
    
    .image-container {
      background-image: url("my-img-1.jpg");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 75%;
      /* Adjust this value to maintain the aspect ratio of the image */
    }
    /* Define the rectangles using absolute positioning */
    
    .rectangle {
      position: absolute;
      border: 2px solid red;
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
      /* Light shade of transparent red */
      z-index: 1;
      /* Ensure the rectangles appear above the image */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-container" style=" background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300); padding-bottom: 100%;">
    <!-- Define the rectangles using the provided coordinates -->
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;"></div>
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 50%; left: 60%; width: 20%; height: 30%;"></div>
    <!-- Add more rectangles as needed -->
  </div>
  <div class="image-container" style=" background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300); padding-bottom: 150%;">
    <!-- Define the rectangles using the provided coordinates -->
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 10%; left: 20%; width: 30%; height: 40%;"></div>
    <div class="rectangle" style="top: 50%; left: 60%; width: 20%; height: 30%;"></div>
    <!-- Add more rectangles as needed -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Nowadays browsers recognise the aspect-ratio property and you could investigate using that instead of the padding 'fiddle' perhaps.

Comment: thank you I think I understand, just a few questions.

1. you use two images to demonstrate a 300x300 and a 200x300 image and then you change the padding bottom directly in the image container div to make sure the aspect ratio is correct. Can you instead do this change this in the image container class in the styling css near the top?

2. assuming the padding bottom creates a correct aspect ratio, will all the rectangles be correctly placed regardless of the browser window size? for example if the window is really small, will the rectangles appear in the correct relative position still?

Comment: 1. You need to set the % padding (or the aspect-ratio if you go that route) secifically for each image container. If you want to put the settings into the style sheet you will have to have a way of selecting each image and making sure to set the right ratios. You could of course do this with classes. Personally in this particular scenario where you already have very specific info about an image (viz the position of its rectangles) in the HTML I'd keep the aspect ratio info alongside them in the HTML too. 2. Try it! The whole thing should be responsive as it's using %s.

Comment: Whops! I just noticed that my second example is for an aspect ratio 2/3 not 3/4 as I had originally. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%; 
  left: 40%; 
  width: 55%; 
  height: 45%;
  border: red solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
  <span class="outline"></span>
</div>
```